# 500 Internal Server Error After upgrading magento from 2.1.7 to 2.2.2

Tags: magento2.2

I have updated magento through the command line.When i checked the version, it was successfully upgraded to 2.2.2, but while accessing the frontend and backend...Iam getting the **500 Internal Server Error**.

And in reindex I am getting the error:

**Table "CatelogInventory_Stock_Status_Replica" doesnot exist.**

**Catalog Rule Index, Catalog Product Rule Index and Stock Indexes are failed.**

Do any one have experienced this, please suggest ....

> Iam stuck with the Magento upgrade please help....

Comment: folder and file permission might got lost. Please set appropriate permissions for folders and files and see if its OK.

Comment: Hi ...Thank you for your response...
Can you please suggest the exact permissions and for which files and folders...

Comment: https://magehit.com/blog/magento-2-file-folder-permissions-setting/

Comment: also; http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/prod/prod_file-sys-perms.html

Comment: check above 2 links

Comment: Hi,
I have run the following commands:

find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;                        // 644 permission for files

find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;                        // 755 permission for directory 

find ./var -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;                // 777 permission for var folder    

find ./pub/media -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;

find ./pub/static -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;

chmod 777 ./app/etc

chmod 644 ./app/etc/*.xml

But still 500 Error cant access backend and frontend

Comment: ok, did you reindexed, deployed etc?

Comment: Before i have done..
Do i need to do after changing the file permissions?

Comment: php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
-->after running the above ,it was showing in red as "Use Quick strategy Deploy" and at the end again showing in red color "Execution time:xxx.xxxxxx"
Is there any issue with this...

And after running 
php bin/magento indexer:reindex

Comment: no issues with it. still there is issue?

Comment: Yes Still 500 Error

Comment: ok, please check magento error log. Also if possible, please see server error log as well. There should be  a clue left behind.

Comment: I have checked in /var/log/exception.log
Here a critical error:
main.CRITICAL: Dotmailer connector API endpoint cannot be empty. {"exception":"[object] (Magento\\Framework\\Exception\\LocalizedException(code: 0): Dotmailer connector API endpoint cannot be empty. at /public_html/vendor/dotmailer/dotmailer-magento2-extension/Model/Apiconnector/Client.php:118)"} []

Comment: I have disabled the Dotmailer module..but not solved 500 error

Comment: it should have worked out. detailed checking might be need i think.